# Get sheets names from google spreadsheets docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

What I mean.

I have a link to the [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/*SomeHash*](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/_SomeHash_) . I want with JS connect by the link and get all exist sheets names or ids.

Is possible solutions fo such case?

Answer (score 0):

write code in Google app Script to get sheet names of spreadsheet and deploy your script. hit this web service using ajax call (in JS). return these sheet name list from your app script.